# Cant configure Flask on Apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, flask, deployment

Good morning everyone!
I can't deploy a flask app on a google virtual machine with ubuntu installed.
I put the whole app in a folder called pyapp and I created a virtual env.
The app is running locally with virtual env activate, if I launch it with the python3 path to app.py command I get no errors and the apps runs.
At the same level as the app I created the app.wsgi file

```py
import sys
import logging

sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/pytask')
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/pytask/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/')

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)

from app import app as application
```

Then I create with command `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/pytask.conf`
this conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ***
        ServerAdmin ***
        ServerAlias ***
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        WSGIDaemonProcess pytask threads=5 python-home=/var/www/html/pytask/venv
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/pytask/pytask.wsgi
        <Directory pytask>
                WSGIProcessGroup pytask
                WSGIScriptReloading On
                Require all granted
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

i disabled the 000-default site and activated with a2ensite command this file.
but when I go to the site the browser gives me back:

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at *** Port 80.

I can't figure out what the problem is...

i disabled the 000-default site and activated with a2ensite command this file.
but when i go to the site the browser gives me back:

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.
> Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at *** Port 80.

I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: yes but still dont work...